# How can I prevent the images in my bootstrap card to stop appearing TRUNCATED

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I used bootstrap card to display products on my ecommerce site. I attempted to set all the product images in the card to the same height with using some custom CSS. The images resize well but are truncated at the top.

How can i prevent them from getting truncated?

```
//HTML
<!-- card for products -->
<div class="card-deck h-100">      
<div class="card border-secondary">
<img src="image.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fliud"><!-- card image here -->
<div class="card-body">
Other Card Text here...
</div>
<div>
<div>



//CSS
/* Equal-height for product images*/
.card-img-top {
    /*height: 11vw;*/
    max-height: 230px;
    min-height: 230px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

sample codes are welcome.

[image: See truncated images here..]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`object-position: 100% 0%;`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-position/)

(change class `img-fliud` to `img-fluid`)

```css
.card-img-top {
  /*height: 11vw;*/
  max-height: 230px;
  min-height: 230px;
  width: 100%;
  object-position: 100% 0%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck h-100">
    <div class="card border-secondary">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/img_avatar1.png" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
      <!-- card image here -->
      <div class="card-body">
        Other Card Text here...
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
        </div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Thanks for the answer...this helped...problem solved....thank you brother

Answer (score 0):

You have spelled wrongly. It's not img-fliud its img-fluid.
I think it should fix.